# How to scrape data from a table with multiple pages in Python using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from a webpage that is inside a small table with multiple pages. I want to get all the information from the table of all pages. However, the URL doesn't change when clicking to a new page which makes it hard for me to get to the new page using BeautifulSoup in Python.

What can I do?

Thank you!

Ive tried to use beautifulSoup

Comment: How *exactly* did you try? Please show us your code, even if it doesn't work. Also, we can't guess what the site looks like, and don't want to try; you can either give a link to that site or paste it HTML here so that we can have a look.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Developer Tools -> Network tab. This tab will show you all the requests which are sent by the webpage. Then press the button to move to the next page and look for new requests in Network tab. You can then inspect this request and you are likely to find that request's url changes with each page.

You can copy this request by pressing Right click on request -> copy as curl(bash) and inserting it into Insomnia or Postman. Or you can just visit request's url in a browser.

Based on how the url changes, you can set up a for loop.